# Conditional routing for searching in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, routes

In Laravel 7 on PHP 7.4. I have a GET route at `/search`, which is routed to a `SearchController`'s `index` method. That renders the form. The user fills in a search term and POSTs it, also to `/search` (with its own separate route), which maps to the `SearchController`'s `results` method. That's all good.

The results use pagination on the collection, and the links generated by the paginator are of the form `/search?searchterm=foo&page=2`, and these of course result in GET requests. The problem is that a GET to the `/search` endpoint, with or without URL params always goes to the form view. I'm not clear how I should set up my routes so that a POST to `/search` is handled by the same controller method as a GET with query params.

I'm starting with this, which renders the form, accepts search requests, and displays the *first* page of results correctly, but requests for other pages with pagination params end up back on the search form:

```php
Route::get('search', 'SearchController@index')->name('search.index');
Route::post('search', 'SearchController@results')->name('search.results');
```

This is what I've tried so far, accepting requests to both GET and POST, checking the input, and sending it to appropriate controller method:

```php
Route::match(['get', 'post'], 'search', function () {
    if (request()->filled('searchterm')) {
        Route::post('search', 'SearchController@results')->name('search.results');
    } else {
        Route::get('search', 'SearchController@index')->name('search.index');
    }
});
```

This does... nothing at all, just a blank screen for both GET and POST with no errors logged, so I assume it's not matching anything. I really don't know if you can put one route definition inside another like that. The repetition of the `search` path inside it feels wrong too. I've found examples similar to this that return different views directly from the route, but I want to send it to the controller as usual.

To clarify, a POST to `/search` should hit the same controller method and produce the same results as a GET to `/search?searchterm=foo&page=1`.

In my view I'm generating pagination links with:

```
{{ $items->withQueryString()->links() }}
```

How should I route these requests? Using `redirect()`? Some way of defining a route that matches query params?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply check if memthod is `post` or `get` and decide what to do for each case.

**SearchController**

```
class SearchController extends Controllr {
  public function index(Request $request){
    // you do any conditions check here ... 
    if($request->isMethod('post')) {
      return $this->postSearch($request);
    }

    // Get code here
  }


  public function postSearch(Request $request){
    // Post code here
  }
}
```

Route files:

**web.php**

```
Route::match(['post', 'get'], '/search', 'SearchController@index')->name('search');
```

Comment: That's just moving the same problem to inside my controller? It's not as simple as GET vs POST – that's the situation I'm starting with.

Answer (score 0):

As soon as you use `Route::match(['get', 'post'], 'search', function () {...` the callback becomes the result, which means the dispatching has already happend. You may add Routes, buts its already too late. So you have to match before dispatching.

Place an `echo` in your callback and you will see :)

You can do this:

#### `routes`

```
Route::get('/', 'SearchController@index');
Route::post('/', 'SearchController@results');
```

#### `controller`

```
class SearchController extends Controller {
    public function index(Request $request) {
        if ($request->has('searchterm')) {
            return $this->results($request);
        }

        return view(/* ... */);
    }

    public function results(Request $request) {
        return view(/* ... */);
    }
}
```

**Malkhazi Dartsmelidze** kind of got it first though :D

Comment: The docs show the `where` matching on named URL params rather than query string params – it doesn't seem to match my paginated requests

Comment: Dang ok, query - in this case we can use a [filter](https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/routing#route-filters) and redirect, since we got the request there. - Still not sure if there is a way to match before. Ill experiment later :)